# Phonegap config.xml reverts after build

Tags: cordova

Using the command line to build a project `cordova build android` the changes I make in config.xml found in `project_name\platforms\android\res\xml` revert back the original `config.xml`. I am trying to change the version number, description and author etc.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the changes in the app/config.xml file. Note that before version 3.3.1-0.2.0, the file existed at app/www/config.xml